# Buenas prácticas para hacer un setState

Tags: reactjs

Supongamos que tengo un arreglo de personas:

```
this.state = {
    personas: [
        {nombre: "Genarito"},
        {nombre: "Carlos"}
    ]
};
```

Supongamos que quiero cambiar el nombre solo del primer elemento, cuál es el mejor método y por qué, esto para mi es importante ya que el proyecto es grande y me gustaría utilizar buenas prácticas siempres que sea posible:

```
this.state.personas[0].nombre = "Otro nombre";
this.forceUpdate();
```

Ó

```
this.state.personas[0].nombre = "Otro nombre";
this.setState(personas: this.state.personas);
```

O sería más prolijo usando variables auxiliares?

Cualquier tipo de ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera de hacerlo según la documentación oficial es a través del método `setState`.
Este ejemplo te muestra como hacerlo como te indicaba Hugo.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      personas: [
        { id: 1, nombre: "Adolfo" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "Juan" }
      ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let personas = this.state.personas
    personas.forEach(item => {
      if (item.id === 2) item.nombre = "Jose"
      return item
    })
    this.setState({ personas })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.personas)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="App-intro">
          { 
            this.state.personas 
            ? this.state.personas.map((item, index) => {
              return <p key={index}>
                {this.state.personas[index].id} - {this.state.personas[index].nombre}
              </p>         
            })
            : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba! Que ya lo hagan en la documentación oficial afianza la confianza. Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, lo mas optimo es si vas a trabajar con objetos o json es tener un identificador por cada valor, algo como esto:

```
this.state = {
    personas: [
        {id:1,nombre: "Genarito"},
        {id:2,nombre: "Carlos"}
    ]
};
```

Entonces a la hora de querer hacer algún cambio, corres un forEach recorriendo el objeto y comparando los ids con el del que quieres cambiar, una ves lo encuentras, haces el cambio, obviamente para esto, los ids deben de ser únicos, así es como trabajan las bases de datos por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero la pregunta es cuál es el mejor método para cambiar el estado `forceUpdate` o `setState(miVariable)` o usar variables auxiliares. Mis objetos ya tienen ID como dices.